# nginx returns error_code, which has named location mapped in server scope

Tags: nginx

I am using named location for forwarding request to certain named blocks based on certain conditions. 
This is how my current config looks like

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;


    error_page 420 = @handler;

    location / {
        if ($http_x_client = 'handler'){
             return 420;
        }
        error_page 500 = @fallback;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass  http://www.example.com;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

   location @fallback{
        proxy_pass  http://www.example2.com;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

   location @handler{
        proxy_pass  http://www.example3.com;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

}
```

Now when i am hitting the page including the header X_Client=handler it's returning 420 status instead of going to @handler block. 
I have narrowed it down to a issue with the line

```
error_page 500 = @fallback;
```

Can someone what's wrong with this configuration or is this is a expected nginx behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quote from [the documentation](http://nginx.org/r/error_page):

> `error_page` directives are inherited from the previous level only if there are no `error_page` directives defined on the current level.

It's a basic rule for most of the directives in nginx.